# Google calendar API (Events: list): get accepted events only

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way to fetch only events accepted by the user making the request to Calendar API?

The ["Calendar API Event: list" doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) does not give much hope, but in the response, in the `attendees` property, I see a `"responseStatus": "declined"` key value for declined events, so obviously the info is there:

```json
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
     "self": true,
     "responseStatus": "declined"
    },
    ...
   ], ...
```

I would like to avoid to filter the response object manually.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:

It seems like there's no direct way of filtering out or only show the ***accepted*** `responseStatus` using the [Calendar API Event: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) API tester. However, you may want to possibly use some scripting to filter the events automatically to only show the ones with ***accepted*** `responseStatus`. Here's a sample script below using [Apps Script](https://script.google.com/) with [Calendar API added on the Apps Script Editor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services):

> **This sample script was derived from [Listing events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_events)**

```
/**
 * Lists the next 10 upcoming events in the user's default calendar.
 */
function listNext10Events() {
  var calendarId = 'CALENDAR_ID'; //replace the calendar ID here
  var now = new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: now.toISOString(),
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
      try{
        if(event.attendees[0].responseStatus == 'accepted'){
          Logger.log("Event: "+ event.summary +
                     " \nGuest: " + event.attendees[0].email +
                     "\nGuest Response: " + event.attendees[0].responseStatus + 
                     "\nTime: "+ new Date(event.start.dateTime).toLocaleDateString() +
                     " to " + new Date(event.end.dateTime).toLocaleDateString());
        }else{
          Logger.log("Event: "+ event.summary +
                     " \nGuest: " + event.attendees[0].email +
                     "\nGuest Response: " + event.attendees[0].responseStatus + 
                     "\nTime: "+ new Date(event.start.dateTime).toLocaleDateString() +
                     " to " + new Date(event.end.dateTime).toLocaleDateString());
        }
      }catch{
        Logger.log("The event" + event.summary + " has no guests");
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
  }
}
```

### Sample Result:

[image]